# Inputs like on Squareup.com

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to achieve text inputs like those on [Square's website](http://squareup.com). Essentially, inputs that have the `<label>` in them. When you click inside of it, the text becomes lighter and when you start typing, it disappears. I previously found a snippet but since it was `position:absolute;`, it ended up screwing my design.

Comment: Instead of using a label you can just set the value of the input and use javascript onfocus to remove the text..or when they start typing

Comment: that site uses absolute positioning to achieve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jAp8k/2/) that solves your problem. I'm absolutely positioning the label element, then relatively positioning the field element, which puts it slightly higher in the stacking order. Set the field background to transparent, and add some jQuery to listen for focus events. Bam.

(edit: oops, I didn't keep the focus effect when you enter stuff into the field)

Comment: Technically, this works. For some reason, though, the text doesn't disappear when you start typing. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: set the visibility to hidden in the .focus class

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just me but there seems to be a slight lag. When I start typing, the text disappears but not right away. This is minor, but if you know what's the fix for this, it would be great.

Comment: So I ended up trying the snippet that I tried before (http://attardi.org/labels/) and it works exactly like it should. I fixed the position:absolute; problem in my design, so it's ok. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

That's known as a watermark. There are a few jQuery plugins available for that.

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted to know what that "effect" is known as, or whether you were after that specific behaviour. Some of my colleagues have used watermarks, but I don't know the specifics of how they behave

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2nN9/) that doesn't use CSS 
:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>

function focusMe(who)
{
    if (who.value == "my label")
    {
        who.value = "";
    }
}

function blurMe(who)
{
    if (who.value == "")
    {
        who.value = "my label";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="my label" onfocus="focusMe(this)" onblur="blurMe(this)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Square is using HTML5 as well, with the input tag they add

```
<input class=".input" placeholder="Whatever it should say prior to the click">
```

Then to change the color once the box is typed into, use  the pseudo class :focus

```
.input {
      color:#999999;
}

/* This will give you the change of color */
.input:focus {
      color:#000000;
}
```